# Static IP for Cloud Service on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a `Cloud Service` that has Worker Role. Cloud Service is set to scale at 5 instances. There is an operation that requires communication from Azure to our data center. For the communication to happen, we have to Whitelist the IP address.

My question is that since I have set the `Cloud Service` to have 5 instances, do I need 5 static IPs or 1?

Also how does this pan out if I set it to `Auto Scale?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All five (or any number of) instances in a single Cloud Service sit behind a single IP address.

The assigned IP address for the cloud service doesn't change unless you deprovision and reprovision the service (`xyz.cloudapp.net`). So, if you resolved your `cloudapp.net` name to an IP address, you'd be able to whitelist that IP address (until such time that you take down the Cloud Service. Then the IP address is lost).

If you want to ensure that you always know the IP address, even if you deprovision / reprovision, you can set up a reserved IP address in Azure, and then assign it to the Cloud Service.

More info on reserved IP addresses [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/).

Comment: This may be true for inbound connection to the cloud service (Using Load Balancer). I am making outbound connections from the Cloud Service which essentially are made from the VMs (Instances). I do not think all the connection coming to the data center will be coming from the same IP.

Comment: All outbound traffic from your web / worker role instances within a cloud service will come from the cloud service's IP address. Same IP address as inbound.

Comment: interesting. Not sure how though. Not saying you are wrong but it is my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Behold, the magic of NAT and the Azure load balancer. :)  It's how Azure has always worked. You can also assign instance-level IP addresses for a given role instance, but that's out of scope for your question. FYI you can always RDP into one of your instances and visit one of the websites that tell you your ip address, so that you can see this is how it works...

Comment: but when i restart the VMS imagine, when my cloud service only has 1 VM running, and i restart it, will this be the same as the deprovision? and thus, the cloud service ip will change? ( because i need to assign the A record of my naked domain to that ip of the cloudservice.

Comment: @Miguel You're posting a question, as a comment, within a closed question. Given that it's infrastructure-related, I suggest posting a new question on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.